# fv formula in excel

Tags: excel-formula, finance

I would like to know the following: in the FV formula, can I use both the PMT and PV or I should use either the PMT or the PV?

The problem is the following:
You have invested 75000 in a trust fund at r=0,075. You will draw $12000 per year from this fund for 4 years, starting at the end of the year 7. 
What will be the amount that will be left over in this fund at the end of the year 10?

The correct calculation is to find the FV of $75000 at the end of year 10 and then to subtract the accumulated PMT over the last 4 years.

However, I calculated the FV(period=7) and then by using FV(period=7) as a PV, I tried to calculate the FV(at period=10) by using both PMT and PV [which equals FV(period=7)]. At the end I get the wrong number. What it's wrong with it?

What happens if I use both PMT and PV in the FV formula? I assumed that based on the PV [which equals FV(period=7)], the formula subtracted each time the corresponding PMT and thus at the end (period=10) the remaining value would be the "left over" in period 10. But I don't get the correct number. So what happens if I use both the PV and PMT in the FV formula? What is the number I get by using both PMT and PV?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if I use both PMT and PV in the FV formula?

Essentially the same as if you used them individually (*ceteris paribus*) and then added their results.

This is not entirely intuitive (IMO) as the timing of the future value is different. I suspect that is your issue with trying to recalculate part way through the term, but it is impossible to be sure without your actual numbers.

A simple example, assuming annual or a one off payment of 100 at 10% pa for three years:

[image: SO42833178 example]

Three formulae shown emboldened and their results on the same line. Running through the steps in English:

Receive 100 at the start of Year1 so are liable for 10 interest at the end of that year (110 outstanding).
Receive 100 at the start of Year2 so are liable for interest on (110+100) at the end of that year =21 (231 outstanding).
Receive 100 at the start of Year3 so are liable **at the start of Year3** for **331.00**.

Receive 100 at the start of Year1 so are liable for 10 interest at the end of that year (110 outstanding).
At the end of Year2 further interest, of 11, outstanding.
**At the end of Year3** further interest, of 12.1, outstanding, total then **133.10**.

Moral: Seems to be, **don't** use both in the same formula :)